# In symfony app Images are not shown and script do not run

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I am new to Symfony and I need to add images and scripts (from js files).

Under the folder **web** I have **/img** and **/js**.

In **base.html.twig** template I use it like this :

```
<link href="img/brand.png" rel="shortcut icon">
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<img src="img/brand.png" alt="" />
```

I test it with *app.php* and *app_dev.php* (also trying to clear chace in both cases).

I am using vhost configured as

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/symfony/myproject/web/app_dev.php/"
ServerName myprojectdev
```

Images are not shown and script do not run. The request header return 404 and the URL is http:`//myprojectdev/js/main.js`. If I modify the header in http:`//localhost/symfony/myprojectdev/app_dev.php/js/main.js` the Status is 200.

I found documentation about [Best Practice](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html) and [Components](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html). For the moment i would not to use Assetic Bundle but I do not understand if I have to install the component in order to use the syntax

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('img/brand.png') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
<img src="{{ asset('img/brand.png') }}" alt="" />
```

Comment: Check in browser's developer tools what URL is it trying to access for images/js. What I can say is that you should use slash (`/`) before file paths. Without it, browser will request relative url e.g. when you go to `http://example.com/app_dev.php/some-page`, browser will try to download `http://example.com/app_dev.php/some-age/js/main.js` instead of `http://example.com/js/main.js`

Comment: @dragoste : I follow your suggestion. The status code is 404 with or without the slash (/). I realized that I am using vhost so I correct the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, add slashes before file paths as I mentioned in my comment, so you should have HTML like this:

```
<link href="/img/brand.png" rel="shortcut icon">
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
<img src="/img/brand.png" alt="" />
```

Next you have incorrect `DocumentRoot` in your vhost configuration

It should be

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/symfony/myproject/web/"
```

As [Apache's documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) says: `DocumentRoot` is

> **Directory** that forms the main document tree visible from the web.

`app_dev.php` is a file, which should be included in root path.

Comment: @dragosta : that's it. I configured the vhost in that way in order to use always _app_dev.php_ for the URL myproject*dev* . There is a better practice to switch between app.php and app_dev.php? In any case now i can keep studing.